# C# foreaching through list<struct> won't change values

Tags: c#, foreach, addressing

I have a struct holding condition informations.

```
private struct hintStructure
{
    public string id;
    public float  value;
    public bool   alreadyWarned;
}
private List<hintStructure> hints;
```

Whenever my program changes a value, an event is sent and the condition list is checked wether that element meets a condition.

```
public void EventListener (string id)
{
    CheckHints(id); //id of the updated element
}

private void CheckHints(string _id) 
{
    foreach (hintStructure _h in hints)
        if (_h.id == _id) CheckValue(_h);
}

private void CheckValue(hintStructure _h)
{
    float _f = GetValue(_h.id);

    if (_f < _h.value)
    {
        ActivateHint(_h);
        _h.alreadyWarned = true;
    }
    else 
        _h.alreadyWarned = false;
}

private void ActivateHint(hintStructure _h)
{
    if(_h.alreadyWarned == false)
        ShowPopup();
}
```

`ShowPopup()` should only be called, when it wasn't already shown for that specific element (indicated by `bool alreadyWarned`). Problem is: It's always shown. It seems like the line `_h.alreadyWarned = true;` is called, but the value isn't stored (I checked if it gets called, it does).
I assumed the `foreach` might be the problem (since it was buggy some years ago), but it doesn't work with a `for()` structure either.

My last guess is an addressing issue, typical problem in *C++*:
`CheckValue(h); vs. CheckValue(&h);` But if I'm correct with this guess - how can I solve this?

Comment: The problem isn't `foreach` itself - it's your use of mutable structs. *Don't do that*. Beyond that, it's very hard to see what's wrong when you haven't shown the loop that's supposedly causing the problem. Please include a [mcve], and then stop using mutable structs...

Comment: C++ != C#. In other words, you should generally not be using `struct` in C# until you really understand the difference and need any performance improvements that may be gained.

Comment: @JonSkeet its not that he is addressing a struct as mutable - its because hes changing the struct on the top of the stack expecting that change to persist beyond the stack call.

Comment: @PhillipH: Well, we suspect that's the case. But we can't see the code, which makes it harder to tell for sure. (That's certainly a problem in `CheckValue`, admittedly.) But what I *am* pretty sure about is that if you avoid mutable structs (and public fields!) it's harder to get into this sort of situation.

Comment: I'd also strongly advise starting to follow .NET naming conventions, too...

Comment: It boils down to : mutable structs are **evil**

Comment: Thanks! C# indeed is not C++, the use of structs results from my C++ based education. I won't do it anymore! Changing the struct to a class solved the problem.
@Jon Skeet: I'll have a look in the .NET naming conventions. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is structs in **C#** are value type, so when you call `CheckValue(_h)` you are creating a copy of `_h` and that copy is updated, but original in the list remains intact.

The classic solution is passing this instance by reference (`ref`), but you can't do it with `foreach` variables.

The solution is change `hintStructure` to class:

```
private class Hint
{
    public string id;
    public float  value;
    public bool   alreadyWarned;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are passing a struct, not a class instance. Changes to a struct (not passed as ref) are changing the local copy of the struct. You are trying to make the struct as a reference type.

Changes made to a struct within a function do not change the value of the originating struct - the struct is copied to the stack before being passed up to the function.